# IndexOutOfBounds Exception, cause not apparent

Tags: java

I can't quite figure out what is causing this code to throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception. I think I'm probably just missing something clear.

If my input string is `$15`, what is causing the exception and what do I need to change to stop the exception occurring?

```
if(token.contains("$"))
{
    System.out.println("$ found");
    int symbolPosition = token.indexOf("$");
    int currentPosition = symbolPosition;
    String afterSymbol = ""; //the string succeeding the $ character, up until the end of the string or a , or ) is met
    char nextChar = '\0';

    for(; currentPosition < token.length(); currentPosition++)
    {
        if(token.charAt(currentPosition) != ',' || token.charAt(currentPosition) != ')')
        {
            char nChar = token.charAt(currentPosition+1);
            afterSymbol = afterSymbol.concat(Character.toString(nextChar));
        }
    }
```

Console output:

```
$15
Token $15 is of type 3
$ found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
```

Comment: Note sure, but you are checking `currentPosition < token.length()` in the loop and then accessing `token.charAt(currentPosition+1)` so might need to change the for loop bounds

Comment: `char nChar = token.charAt(currentPosition+1);` looks very suspicious (note the `+1`).

Comment: well if they direct to your known answer it wil bcome apparrent won;t it???!!

Comment: token.charAt(3) cause the exception

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the nChar line of

```
 for(; currentPosition < token.length(); currentPosition++)
        {
            System.out.println(currentPosition);
            if(token.charAt(currentPosition) != ',' || token.charAt(currentPosition) != ')')
            {
                char nChar = token.charAt(currentPosition+1);
                afterSymbol = afterSymbol.concat(Character.toString(nextChar));
            }
        }
```

The Variable currentPosition has a value of 2 in the first iteration of the for-loop. When it tries to create the nChar variable, the code tries to access the `current position +1`, or the 3rd position, of the input. In this specific case, the token `$` is also the last character in the string, so executing the for loop will always result in an out of bounds exception when `$` is the last character. To fix this problem, I would suggest changing the for-loop to

```
for(; currentPosition < token.length()-1; currentPosition++)
```

So that when the for loop executes there will always be a character at `token.charAt(currentPosition+1);`.

Ask if you have any questions.